# Writing momentum 4vector as an integral over the EM stress-energy tensor

Tags: tensors, general-relativity, electromagnetism

I have been watching a series of lectures on general relativity by Neil Turok and I have run into a problem.

In one of the lectures, the professor writes the momentum 4-vector as a contraction of the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor with the epsilon tensor inside an integral. He first writes it in the following way:

$p^\gamma = \int_Vd^3xT^{\gamma 0}$

and then claims that this is proportional to the following

$\int_V T^{\gamma\mu}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}dx^\nu dx^\alpha dx^\beta$

being proportional with only a factor of 1/6th since there are 6 permutations for which $\mu$ = 0

I dont understand this. I would think that by the antisymmetric nature of $\epsilon$, there would be 6 parts summed over, where 3 are the exact negative of the other 3, resulting in a final value of 0. I dont think the order of the dx's should matter. Can someone explain if I'm wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: I don' fully understand how you view the the integral of a p-form over the manifold M, but in general $\int_Mt dV_n=\int t_{12\dots n}dx^1 dx^2\dots dx^n$ where the integrand is a scalar density of weight -1, ie $t_{12\dots n}=\frac{1}{n!} \varepsilon^{\mu_1\dots \mu_n}t_{\mu_1\dots \mu_n}$

Comment: Im really new to the subject and just getting used to working with tensors, so I also dont fully understand haha. Could you maybe elaborate on why this is the case in general? I would think that the antisymmetry of the epsilon would result in the summed terms to cancel out. Since all permutations, even and odd, are summed.